# gridview control - RowEditing event - second click

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, gridview

In gridview control, am using RowEditingevent. I have created a command field to handle insert, cancel and update.

Problem : When click edit (manage.jpg), it is not showing in edit mode. If I do one more click, on the same edit, it is showing data fields to edit. I do not understand why it is not responding for the first click event.

```
    <asp:CommandField 
           ShowEditButton="true"
           ShowCancelButton="True"
           ButtonType="Image" 
           EditImageUrl="manage.jpg"
           HeaderText="Edit" 
           UpdateImageUrl="insert.jpg" 
           CancelImageUrl="cancel.png"
           ItemStyle-Width="10px" >
           <ItemStyle Width="20px" Height="20px"></ItemStyle>
          </asp:CommandField>

    protected void gridFavoriteAddress_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)     {
        gridFavoriteAddress.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        //gridFavoriteAddress.DataBind();
    }
```

Comment: Does the event only get fired on the second click - just to be clear. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just some thoughts

1. When you click on edit the first time does that rebind the grid before the edit event has fired. I have known that disturb the event model
2. Try adding `CausesValidation="false"` to the Command field just in case some failed validation is blockng it the first time through
3. Try recoding it to use an `ImageButton` with a `CommandName="Edit"` in a `TemplateColumn`. This should also fire the row editing event. Does that one work?
4. This is mad - but you've got conflicting styles (widths) in the command button. I would just remove. I know it couldn't possibly cause it but I would just make sure everything is exactly as it should be when going through this

Answer (score -1):

===> //gridFavoriteAddress.DataBind();

Uncomment ==> `gridFavoriteAddress.DataBind();`

Binding grid will resolve the problem..